# Does negative pH mean it is a stronger acid than one with positive pH?

Tags: acid-base, ph

I've searched this site but I don't think this has been asked yet. Does negative pH indicate a stronger acid than a positive pH (since it's further down the scale)? I'm asking this because in one of the problems from my homework set, they asked "which of the following solutions contains the strongest acid?" and one of the options yielded a negative value.

Comment: Negative pH does indicate a _strong_ acid for sure, but it isn't necessarily stronger than that in the other (less acidic) solution. Maybe the latter solution is just more dilute.